# CSV formatting destroys my Algorithm to replace customer data

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, formatting

I am trying to create a Script which replace the customer data (e.g. companyName) with Random picked names. My problem is that the CSV-File (line 3) has a break inside the column data

("Login: #BREAK# #BREAK# USERNAME #BREAK# EMAIL #BREAK# Passwort: *********").

My example CSV-File looks something like this (I've abbreviated it and replaced the customer data):

```
"607";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"686";"companyName";"street";"PLZ";"CITY";"";"0";"";"1";"N";"F";"customer";"0";"4";"7";"1";"z";"d";"d";"d";"d";"d";"0";"Y";"0";"75";"0";"0"
"608";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"687";"companyName";"street";"PLZ";"CITY";"";"0";"";"1";"N";F";"customer";"0";"5";"12";"1";"z";"Y";"d";"d";"d";"d";"0";"Y";"0";"75";"0";"0"
"609";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"688";"companyName";"Street";"PLZ";"City";"";"0";"Login:

USERNAME
EMAIL
Passwort: *******************";"0";"N";"";"";"0";"299";"170";"0";"k";"Y";"d";"d";"d";"d";"0";"";"0";"0";"0";"0"
"610";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"689";"companyName";"Street";"PLZ";"City";"";"0";"";"0";"N";"";"customer";"0";"9";"12";"0";"k";"d";"d";"d";"d";"d";"0";"";"0";"0";"0";"0"
"611";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"690";"companyName";"Street";"PLZ";"City";"";"0";"";"0";"N";"";"customer";"0";"24";"21";"0";"k";"Y";"d";"d";"d";"d";"0";"";"0";"0";"0";"0" '
```

In my Script I wrote that after every break the Array gets the value of everything after last break and before next break.

For better understanding: the Array looks like this after the first loop pass:

```
"607";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"686";"companyName";"Street";"PLZ";"City";"";"0";"";"1";"N";"";"customer";"0";"4";"7";"1";"z";"d";"d";"d";"d";"d";"0";"Y";"0";"75";"0";"0""
```

The Array has a size of 31. But when the ID "609" of the CSV-File gets executed I'll get (of course) just this:

```
"609";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"2017-07-10 16:28:32";"688";"companyName";"Street";"PLZ";"City";"";"0";"Login:
```

So my whole algorithm breaks.

Here is my Upload function:

```
function Upload() {
        var vorname = [];  // actually 1000 first names
        var nachname = []; // acutally 1000 surnames
        var cells;
        var strWholeFile = "";
        var lineToReplace = 4;
        var counter;
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                /* Reader.onload function */
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    rows.length = rows.length - 1;
                    console.log(strWholeFile);

                    /** For every "return" the loop will 
                     *  be executed once **/
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

                        if (i == 0) {
                            cells = rows[i].split(";");
                            counter = cells.length;
                        }
                        else {
                            cells = rows[i].split(";");
                        }

                        if (cells.length == counter && i != 0) {
                            cells[lineToReplace] = "\"" + vorname[getRandom(0, 999)] + " " + nachname[getRandom(0, 999)] + "\"";
                        }

                        console.log(strWholeFile);

                        /** For every column the loop will
                         *  be executed once **/
                        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                            strWholeFile += cells[j] + ";";
                            console.log(strWholeFile);
                        }
                        if (cells.length == counter) {
                            strWholeFile += "\n";
                            console.log(strWholeFile);
                        }
                    }
                };
                reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                alert("Dieser Webbrowser unterstützt kein HTML5.");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Bitte wählen Sie einen gültige CSV-Datei aus.");
        }
    }
```

Do any of you have a smart but still simple idea of how I could solve my Problem? I am learning Javascript since 1 Month so I don't know JavaScript that good (I am not a raw recruit).

Comment: Are the line breaks with the login always in the same column or can it be at any column?

Comment: it can be at every column... Thats the problem

Comment: Well then, you can establish a char by char algorithm, which has some status variable like line number, column number, in quotes (""). With that if a break is coming before the last column and string end, you know to read in the breaks as part of the strings.

Comment: I fixed it! If you want to know what I did Check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the line

```
var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
```

to

```
var rows = e.target.result.split("\"\n");
```

Every end of the CSV-File row looks like this:

```
"data"#BREAK
```

so instead of query just the break I query the Quotation Marks AND the break

**Example end of row:**

```
"data"#Break
```

**Example break inside data:**

```
"Login#BREAK

Email[...]"
```